# Create users on B2C tenant : triggered by user creation on AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-management

Use case : A user is created in Azure AD. As soon as the user is created, another account should be created for the user in B2C tenant (as a federated user).

Question : What is the best approach to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no AD trigger** when a user is added or changed currently. The similar [issue](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-trigger-flow-when-user-is-added-or-deleted-in-Azure-AD/td-p/630753) provides a workaround.

> The alternative way should be make sure to create an item in a
> sharepoint list when you add/delete a user in Azure AD, and then you
> create a flow to trigger when an item is created/deleted is sharepoint
> list.

Then you could create user to Azure AD B2C tenant with Microsoft Graph [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Adele Vance",
  "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
  "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
  }
}
```